# Convert LocalDate into Timestamp in Postgres' json column

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have to migrate a column in PostgresDB 9.5.

The table name is testtable and the concerned column is examplecolumn.

In examplecolumn I have this JSON array for example:

```
[{"key":"id","before":null,"after":4371},
{"key":"status","before":null,"after":1},
{"key":"startDate","before":null,"after":1514761200000},
{"key":"endDate","before":null,"after":1546297199000},
{"key":"billingDate","before":null,"after":{"year":2018,"month":"JANUARY","dayOfMonth":15,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":15,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}}}]
```

I want to convert the child with "billingDate" into timestamp in this format:

```
[{"key":"id","before":null,"after":4371},
{"key":"status","before":null,"after":1},
{"key":"startDate","before":null,"after":1514761200000},
{"key":"endDate","before":null,"after":1546297199000},
{"billingDate":1515974400}]
```

I want to keep everything else. First I tried to get these rows like so.

```
SELECT *, examplecolumn::json->4->'after' as export
FROM testtable
WHERE examplecolumn like '%after":{%';
```

But I can't do this with fix index (e.g. 4) and I don't know which row have child objects with this LocalDate, that's why I wrote this where-clause.

How can I do this? I tried so many times with several Postgres JSON functions, but I am fed up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether the question's about converting that data to a timestamp as per the question's title, or about extracting the data as per the question. So this answer is about extracting the data.

Firstly the CTE is simply to randomise the order of the items in the JSON array, to show it gets around the index issue. Obviously you would be performing the query on your table instead. Then the item with "billingDate" is only included in the even results; the odd ones contain the rest of the JSON items and exclude that one.

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT ('[' || STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN CASE WHEN g % 2 = 0 THEN j::TEXT END ELSE j::TEXT END, ',' ORDER BY RANDOM()) || ']')::JSON AS j
        FROM (
                VALUES
                (1, '{"key":"id","before":null,"after":4371}'),
                (1, '{"key":"status","before":null,"after":1}'),
                (1, '{"key":"startDate","before":null,"after":1514761200000}'),
                (1, '{"key":"endDate","before":null,"after":1546297199000}'),
                (2, '{"key":"billingDate","before":null,"after":{"year":2018,"month":"JANUARY","dayOfMonth":15,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":15,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}}}')
        ) AS v(id, j), generate_series(1, 10) AS g
        GROUP BY g
)
SELECT j, (SELECT je->'after' FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(j) AS je WHERE je->>'key' = 'billingDate' AND (je->>'after') IS NOT NULL) AS export
FROM cte
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to only get the items that have "billingDate", then you can add your WHERE clause from your question:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT ('[' || STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN CASE WHEN g % 2 = 0 THEN j::TEXT END ELSE j::TEXT END, ',' ORDER BY RANDOM()) || ']')::JSON AS j
        FROM (
                VALUES
                (1, '{"key":"id","before":null,"after":4371}'),
                (1, '{"key":"status","before":null,"after":1}'),
                (1, '{"key":"startDate","before":null,"after":1514761200000}'),
                (1, '{"key":"endDate","before":null,"after":1546297199000}'),
                (2, '{"key":"billingDate","before":null,"after":{"year":2018,"month":"JANUARY","dayOfMonth":15,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":15,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":1,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}}}')
        ) AS v(id, j), generate_series(1, 10) AS g
        GROUP BY g
)
SELECT j, (SELECT je->'after' FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(j) AS je WHERE je->>'key' = 'billingDate' AND (je->>'after') IS NOT NULL) AS export
FROM cte
WHERE j::TEXT LIKE '%after":{%'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I want to extract data from "billingDate" to create a timestamp and to update the row later. How can I use the tablename instead of hardcoding the array?

Comment: Basically just select from the table instead of the cte: `SELECT *, (SELECT je->'after' FROM JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(examplecolumn::JSON) AS je WHERE je->>'key' = 'billingDate' AND (je->>'after') IS NOT NULL) AS export
FROM testtable
WHERE examplecolumn LIKE '%after":{%'`